# New column on a specific position - filled with values of only one number

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with 20 Columns.
And I want to add a new Column on Position 5, that means Index 4.
There are 1000 rows and I want to fill all the rows with the number 10.

I tried:

```
df.insert(4, 'Number10', '10')
```

But I only get the Error:

`TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

I also tried:

```
df.insert(4, Number10, '')
df['Number10'] = '1'
```

But it is the same Error.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: You can easily create a new column df['new_column'] = 10 , why would u wont to insert it at a specific position, thats redundant

Answer (score 0):

df.insert(4, 'Number10', 10)....in here if you want to fill it with 10, do not enclose the number in quotes.